# Strategy innovation in a repeated game in Game Theory

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

In game theory, a strategy set is normally assumed. This strategy set is fixed and constitutes the only possible actions the player can choose from. In a repeated game, a game is repeated multiple times until convergence or a termination criteria is met. Given a computer memory limitation, 5 strategies out of the millions of possible strategies for each player can only be accomodated. Is there a paper or theory that allows for the replacement of "weak" strategies or does game theory cover this in the model itself.

An example algorithm would be:

> 1) Randomly select 5 strategies from the strategy set (generated by a population-based search algorithm such as the genetic algorithm).
>
> 2) Get the player's payoff for each action using the Method of
>   Successive Averages (MSA).
>
> 3) Remove the strategy that gives the lowest payoff and replace it
>   with a new strategy from the strategy set (not currently in memory and possibly generated by the mutation or crossover operator of a genetic algorithm).
>
> 4) Check termination criteria. If satisfied, terminate. If not
>   satisfied, Repeat steps 2-4.

Comment: what if the termination criteria were satisfied before being tested ?

Comment: The game terminates. The termination criteria is normally assumed to be the difference between the payoff of the selected strategy on a period (a stage or an iteration) and the previous period. This would mean that at least two iterations is required and a new strategy won't terminate the simulation as its previous payoff is zero (0). Thanks.

Comment: I was more pointing to the fact that on a set of strategies ( admittedly I've heard of game theory but never actually practiced it ( plays scholar's mate in chess for example)), you may pick the best 5 right away so by discounting the lowest payout wouldn't that make you get a worse set of 5 strategies to play with a possibility?

Comment: I understand. In this case, I am assuming a game played by millions of players with millions of possible actions at the same time. So the possibility of all the players selecting the best 5 strategies immediately is very remote. Also, I will add in my post that a new strategy is generated using for example mutation or crossover of a genetic algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: Not quite the same, but there is some work applying genetic algorithms to games.